# jsp:include cannot include binary file

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am reading the book "Head First Servlet and JSP". There is one question I cannot fully understand.

[image: page snippet]

I am not sure why the book says that "**it is not possible to import the contents of any binary file into a jsp page, which generates a HTML content**".

Why the above statement is true?

Is it due to run time include a binary file will open a new input stream?

What exception will this cause?

Does this mean even if I use `<%@ include file = "logo.png" @>` to include binary file at compilation time rather than run time, the include will still fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing

> `<jsp:include page="banner.png"></jsp:include>`

results in untranslated codes

² /;ÖXÈ%Ïa€wñÉšª1rÂ<š›AÃrðÖŠf’²dPíDuS3=wÄ RiTêÔjO‡²qç™Ûþ”àÕ$'ûv3(YÛ¹ÏÙ&ÜzíuÄ½þ`ãzŠÛþq=2ÒI_e•5GäÜ†àdKÜËÇ 7Ž>â¶s\ŒtÒKÙ×¾ö·vëDæò}û÷ÿdýSžsÅmÏ¸éd¾²¯þå_ÙgÐù+6?ó…ÂSÇ•#¿¡Eg»ÅõÈH's”½cYsDùÇÁóÁÂôÊ§óÖ›o…ß4v‹ëi´¦)`!È VVVX±åÝ’ð˜‡¶/âb/žXº…i›YYj:Ê‡¼ÛØ„eâùóçYûæÛ,6+¢¬iüdàäÉ“¢Ý˜ú^X;»L@®HN`³yxS¨¨®X²ûS¨Á˜×µlm u(fóKæÔQJÅ,es îõ‡nþ‹}

> `<%@ include file = "banner.png" %>`

results in 500 server error

```
HTTP Error Code:   500

Error Message:
/Login.jsp(44,56) java.io.UTFDataFormatException: JSPG0287E: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Root Cause:
com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: /Login.jsp(44,56) java.io.UTFDataFormatException: JSPG0287E: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.document.Jsp2Dom.getJspDocumentAsJspPage(Jsp2Dom.java:529)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.document.Jsp2Dom.getJspDocument(Jsp2Dom.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslator.<init>(JspTranslator.java:73)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslatorFactory.createTranslator(JspTranslatorFactory.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJsp(JspTranslatorUtil.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJspAndCompile(JspTranslatorUtil.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:560)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:477)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:298)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
```